# Common ground for image sizes when using Photoshop save to web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

Recently, I was working on an image in Photoshop and wanted to save it for web usage. I wanted to know whether there is a good size to go with for the modern design standards when it comes to websites. I am a little hesitant to save it as a 1920 X 1080 simply because it is on the higher end and then use CSS to move it around as a background.

I am also not sure that using the more common 960px as the width will really serve my needs when the viewport size of a browser goes beyond that with all the new resolutions out there.

Furthermore, I am a little concerned with the size of the image and loss of quality as we get into higher resolutions considering that if I start small, I am left with little growing room and then having to deal with a diluted image as the size of the viewport goes up.

Any recommendations or links that talk about this? I am trying to build a site using responsive design and I have seem some JavaScript utilities that let you resize images but I am more concerned with the size of the image to start with and moving from there.

Thanks for any help or suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I personally do:

Save two versions of the images in two different sizes.

- One for 1x resolution devices (most of them)
- One for 2x resolutions devices (like iPad retina). The dimensions of this image are 200% the dimensions of the previous one.

Then, instead of using the *src* attribute of the `<img>` tag, I use CSS to

- Apply the image as a background
- Set the width and high of the image to the dimensions of the 1x resolution one.
- Set *background-dimension* to *contain*. This makes sure the image is stretched to cover the whole `img` tag. Will make sense when you read the next comments.

I set the *src* attribute of the `img` to a transparent gif.

Finally, using media queries, I target the high res devices and change the version of the image to the 2x version. Since the *background-dimension* is still set to *contains*, the 2x image is shrunk to the dimensions of the `img` tag. The dimension stays correct but the device has the extra pixels available that it needs to show the image without blurriness.

**Example**: Suppose you want to show the image of a dog at 120px x 50px but want the image to appear sharp on iPad4 (which has 2x resolution). I save the image with those exact dimensions (dog-r1.jpg) and then to 200% of those dimensions: 240px x 100px (dog-r1.jpg).

This is my HTML

```
<img id="imgDog" src="transparent.gif" alt="" />
```

And this is my CSS

```
#imgDog{
   width:120px;
   height:50px;
   background-image:url(dog-r1.jpg);
   background-size:contain;
}

//iPad 4 media query
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
   background-image:url(dog-r2.jpg); 
}
```

When the page is viewed with an iPad 4, the background image will be replaced with dog-r2.jpg, but will still be displayed at 120x50px. Since the iPad 4 had double the resolution, the image will display at its sharpest best.

This is a very simplistic example, since one does not want to target only one device (iPad 4) but all devices that have more than resolution 1x as a bulk. If you are interested in media queries, there is plenty of resources and discussions online about the topic.

This is a great resource for media queries quick lookups: http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/

Comment: Thanks for the link and I am upvoting this because it talks about using resolution containment versus images that are different. Although, I have nothing against hosting up multiple images for various viewport sizes, I think its an unnecessary step that I am trying to avoid so that I only host maybe three or four images and use their original resolutions to match the viewport sizes letting the responsive design do the rest via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you should save image for different resolution and use them by css media query

and include image according to scree size

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: I like that approach and for the most part, it does solve the issue of taking care of different screen resolutions based on the size of the viewport but now I have to make images in those contained resolutions to solve the issue of a growing space where the image may not necessarily fall into a specific image height/width.